# Camel route to filter out the auto response emails

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel rout to consume the emails from my inbox folder.
But I want to filter out the auto responded emails like out of offices etc.

I see there is a option for to process only unread messages by using option `unseen=true`.

The URI that I am using to consume the emails looks like:

```
pop3://username@host?password=password;delete=true&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=60000
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `searchTerm` property to add to your endpoint URI.

If you want to filter out e-mails with the term **Out Of Office** in them, your endpoint URI might look like this:

```
pop3://username@host.com?password=password;delete=true&searchTerm.subjectOrBody=Out+Of+Office&searchTerm.unseen=true
```

The searchTerm property lets you search on the basis of several other criteria as mentioned below:

1. searchTerm.unseen - Whether to limit by unseen mails only
2. searchTerm.subjectOrBody - To limit by subject or body to contain the word.
3. searchTerm.subject - The subject must contain the word.
4. searchTerm.body - The body must contain the word.
5. searchTerm.from - The mail must be from a given email pattern.
6. searchTerm.to - The mail must be to a given email pattern.
7. searchTerm.fromSentDate/toSentDate - Filters on sent date

Further documentation can be found here - http://camel.apache.org/mail.html

Comment: "searchTerm.from - The mail must be from a given email pattern."

What *is* the email pattern? Where is it specified? I can find nothing in Camel Mail and JavaMail seems not to mention either - at least not htat I find